# Why are manual offsets needed in the ticket package?

Tags: margins

When I use the `ticket` package, the boxes it prints are significantly shifted towards (and past) the right and bottom margins.

It seems that the package author itself had the same problem. He introduced the parameters `\hoffset` and `\voffset` and in his examples sets them to negative values.

Is there a good reason to have to set this offsets manually, or is the package simply badly written? Why can't it align its output with the left and top margins of the page? (I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `ticket` uses `picture` under the hood, but I'd like to know more details.)